# static routes centos 3 nics, 2 gateways

Tags: static, routes, centos

I have this network configuration:

ifcfg-virbr1

```
IPADDR="10.51.51.2"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
GATEWAY="10.51.51.1"
```

route-virbr1

```
10.51.51.0/24 dev virbr1 tab 1
default via 10.51.51.1 dev virbr1 tab 1
```

rule-virbr1

```
from 10.51.51.2/32 tab 1 priority 100
```

ifcfg-virbr3

```
IPADDR="10.0.0.1"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
```

route-virbr3

```
10.0.0.0/24 dev virbr3 tab 3
default via 10.0.0.1 dev virbr3 tab 3
```

rule-virbr3

```
from 10.0.0.1/32 tab 3 priority 300
```

ifcfg-virbr4

```
IPADDR="1.2.3.4"
NETMASK="255.255.255.252"
GATEWAY="1.2.3.3"
```

route-virbr4

```
1.2.3.2/30 dev virbr4 tab 2
default via 1.2.3.3 dev virbr4 tab 2
```

rule-virbr4

```
from 1.2.3.4/32 tab 2 priority 200
```

virbr1 and virbr4 are working perfect. The server's default gateway is 1.2.3.3 through virbr4 and it is also working.

My problem is that virbr3 is connected directly to another server (for backup) and probably because the server's default gateway is 1.2.3.3, I cannot reach it from local. The server behind virbr3 has internet, but it also cannot cannot reach it's gateway (10.0.0.1). Is it a way to solve this problem without adding another router for virbr3 interface?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you